# Measure that should summarize sales for parent company regardless of child company filter

Tags: dax

I have a table with `SalesCompanies`. The table contains one column `ChildCompany` and another column `ParentCompany`.

How can I make the measure below aggregate per `ParentCompany` regardless of `ChildCompany` filtering?

```
CustomerSalesSinceLastInventory:=CALCULATE(
    SUM(factCustomerSales[Quantity])
    ;FILTER(
        ALL(dimCalendar[Date])
        ;dimCalendar[Date] >= MIN(parCurrentMonth[Date])
            && dimCalendar[Date] <= MAX(dimCalendar[Date])
    )
)
```

Comment: I think that I should add an FILTER(ALL(dimSalesCompanies;dimSalesCompanies[ParentCompany]=CORRECT) somehow

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of achieving the desired result:

```
CustomerSalesSinceLastInventory :=
SUMX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( 'dimSalesCompanies'[ParentCompany] );
        "Total sales"; CALCULATE (
            SUM ( [Quantity] );
            ALL ( 'dimSalesCompanies'[Company] );
            FILTER (
                ALL ( dimCalendar[Date] );
                dimCalendar[Date] >= MIN ( parCurrentMonth[Date] )
                    && dimCalendar[Date] <= MAX ( dimCalendar[Date] )
            )
        )
    );
    [Total sales]
)
```

This measure adds a column(in memory, you will not actually see it) which groups/aggregates the sale per ParentCompany. The time filter is also included in this column.